# How to prove that $f, g$ are injective if $f\circ g$ is an injective function?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Considering two functions, $f, g : A → A$ prove or disprove the following

If $f\circ g$ is an injective function then:

- $f$ is injective
- $g$ is injective

Let $f\circ g = h$. If we consider $h$ is injective, then $\exists\ x_1=x_2 : h(x_1)=h(x_2)$. That is basically the same as $g(f(x_1))=g(f(x_2))$, which implies that $g$ is injective. From that we can extrapolate that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, which also implies that $f$ is injective, because $x_1=x_2$, which we considered at the beginning, thus it proves that both, $f$ and $g$ need to be injective, in order of $h$, or $f\circ g$ to be injective.

Is this correct? Can you please give me some hints?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please ask just one question at at time - this is four. You are more likely to get help rather than downvotes or votes to close if you [edit] the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck. Hint. Write down a few examples with small finite domains and codomains.

Comment: I tried to change it the way you suggested. And also, I am trying to figure it out using some examples on paper. Thank you for your input.

Comment: No, it is not correct. The string of symbols $\exists x_1=x_2: h(x_1)=h(x_2)$ is particularly problematic. It suggests you do not understand what being injective actually means.

Comment: "then ∃ x1=x2:h(x1)=h(x2)".  That is *always* true.  No matter *what* $h$ is.  It's impossible for that *not* to be true.

Comment: Let $h(x) = 7$, a constant function.  Let $x_1=x_2 = 5$.  $h(x_1) =h(5) = 7$ and $h(x_2) = h(5) = 7$.  So are you saying $h(x) =7$ is injective.  Or if $h(x) = \sin x$.  Let $x_1 = x_2$ be any angle.  Then $h(x_1) = h(x_2)$.  So is $h$ injective?

Answer (score 1):

This is only a comment/hint, but I don’t have the reputation to leave a comment:

Your definition for injective is wrong. A function $h$ is injective provided if $h(x_{1})=h(x_{2})$, then $x_{1}=x_{2}$. Or, equivalently, $h$ is injective provided if $x_{1}\neq x_{2}$, then $h(x_{1})\neq h(x_{2})$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f\circ g$ is injective, then $g$ must be injective, since, if there existed $a\neq b$ with $g\left(a\right)=g\left(b\right)$, $$f\left(g\left(a\right)\right)=f\left(g\left(b\right)\right),$$ contradicting injectivity.

However, $f$ does not necessarily need to be injective. For example, if $f(x)=\left(x+2\right)^2$, $g(x)=\tan^{-1}\left(x\right)$, $f\circ g$ will be injective, even though $f$ isn’t. To make this claim, you’d need $g$ to be surjective.